# Как получить изображение с веб-камеры?

Tags: камера, linux

Как мне в bash получить изображение с веб-камеры ноутбука? Мне нужно написать скрипт, который получал бы изображение с веб-камеры и залиал его на ФТП с определённым именем.

Answer (score 1):

```
fswebcam -r 640x480 --jpeg 85  -F 3 -S 2 test.jpg  &&  lftp -u user,password  -e  'put ./test.jpg; bye' host.with.ftp.com
```

Немножко поясню. Утилита понятно, скачал из репов поставил, вопросов нет. Параметры -F и -S я ставил потому что у меня странная камера и нормально инициализируется только на 3 фрэйме, поэтому я ловлю 3 (-F), а первые два пропускаю (-S), может вам и не надо их ставить, далее имя файла. Ну а дальше ftp там все тривиально.